# Zend form using same name for two field using array notation

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

Using Zend Framework 1.9. I have a form:

```
...
    $this->addElement('text', 'field', [
        'label' => 'Name (*)',
        'belongsTo' => 'a'
    ]);
    $this->addElement('text', 'field', [
        'label' => 'Name (*)',
        'belongsTo' => 'b'
    ]);

...
```

I am using array notation that produce a nested array like this:

```
array (size=10)
  'a' => 
    array 
      'field' => string '' (length=0)
  'b' => 
    array 
      'field' => string '' (length=0)
```

This notation is usefull for me but when I populate form with an array structure like this:

```
$data=[
       "a"=>
            [
             "field"=>"MY CUSTOM TEXT"
            ],
       "b"=>
            [
             "field"=>"MY SECOND CUSTOM TEXT"
            ]
      ]
$form->populate($data)
```

the form is not populate.

I have read Zend_form doesn't work with fields having same name, but in my case i I am using array notation. I need to use the same name becouse I am using the name of the colum in the database, so in my database I have two table "a","b" with same columm named "field".

There is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using subforms ? I have 1.11, so I don't know, but I was successfully achieving what you want with this code

```
/**
 * Form class that should be in application/forms/Foo.php
 */
class Application_Form_Foo extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $subFormA = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $subFormA->addElement($subFormA->createElement('text', 'field', array
        (
            'label' => 'Name (*)',
            'belongsTo' => 'a',
        )));

        $subFormB = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $subFormB->addElement($subFormB->createElement('text', 'field', array
        (
            'label' => 'Name (*)',
            'belongsTo' => 'b',
        )));

        $this->addSubForm($subFormA, 'a');
        $this->addSubForm($subFormB, 'b');


        $this->addElement($this->createElement('submit', 'send'));
    }
}
```

And the controller

```
/**
 * The controller that both process the request and display the form.
 */
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Get the form.
        $foo = new Application_Form_Foo();

        // Poppulate the form from the request.
        if ($foo->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams()))
        {
            $foo->populate($foo->getValues());
        }

        // Set the form to the view.
        $this->view->form = $foo;
    }
}
```